# how to change color admin dashboard in filament

Tags: laravel, admin, dashboard, laravel-filament

I'm a user filament version 2 in my Laravel 9 project
And now I want to custom admin dashboard
and change color by default.

Summary: I want to customize the color in Laravel-Filament Admin Dashboard

Answer (score 0):

you can customize the colors by using tailwind.config.js [Building themes](https://filamentphp.com/docs/2.x/admin/appearance#building-themes)